# EventSource / Server-Sent Events through Nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra

On server-side using Sinatra with a `stream` block.

```
get '/stream', :provides => 'text/event-stream' do
  stream :keep_open do |out|
    connections << out
    out.callback { connections.delete(out) }
  end
end
```

On client side:

```
var es = new EventSource('/stream');
es.onmessage = function(e) { $('#chat').append(e.data + "\n") };
```

When i using app directly, via `http://localhost:9292/`, everything works perfect. The connection is persistent and all messages are passed to all clients.

However when it goes through Nginx, `http://chat.dev`, the connection are dropped and a reconnection fires every second or so.

Nginx setup looks ok to me:

```
upstream chat_dev_upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:9292;
}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  chat.dev;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://chat_dev_upstream;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Tried `keepalive 1024` in `upstream` section as well as `proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;`in `location`.

Nothing helps :(

No persistent connections and messages not passed to any clients.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Your Nginx config is correct, you just miss few lines.

Here is a "magic trio" making `EventSource` working through Nginx:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
```

Place them into `location` section and it should work.

You may also need to add

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_cache off;
```

That's not an official way of doing it.

I ended up with this by "trial and errors" + "googling" :)

Comment: Having the server respond with a "X-Accel-Buffering: no" header helps a lot! (see: http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Buffering)

Comment: Have you had any luck with this and websockets? The websocket example on the nginx site automatically closes the connection header if nothing is set...

Comment: That didn't work for me, until I also added the following :-

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;

Comment: Your trial-and-error + my first google hit = I love stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: I needed the proxy_buffering off; and proxy_cache off; to get it working.  Thanks to @MalcolmSparks

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but the provided solution didn't work for me. [Maybe take a look?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660399/sse-eventsource-closes-after-first-chunk-of-data-rails-4-puma-nginx)

Comment: You just did the OFFICIAL WAY, great job!
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive

Comment: It works for proxying to webpack-hot-middleware. Thanks!

Comment: It's work for me after adding proxy_buffer_size 0;  Thanks!!

Comment: Is "proxy_http_version 1.1;" absolutely required? By doing so, browser connections will be limited to only 6

Comment: I made it work just by adding "X-Accel-Buffering: no" to the response header

Comment: In context of ngnix ingress inside k8s this answer provides the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560048/sse-broken-after-deploying-with-kubernetes-and-connecting-via-ingress

Comment: While using the official nginx Docker image, either `proxy_http_version 1.1;` or `proxy_buffering off;` were both sufficient on their own.

Answer (score 39):

Another option is to include in your response a 'X-Accel-Buffering' header with value 'no'. Nginx treats it specially, 
see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solving the problem without changing nginx config

Answer (score 14):

Don't write this from scratch yourself. Nginx is a wonderful evented server and has modules that will handle SSE for you without any performance degradation of your upstream server.

Check out https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module

The way it works is the subscriber (browser using SSE) connects to Nginx, and the connection stops there. The publisher (your server behind Nginx) will send a POST to Nginx at a corresponding route and in that moment Nginx will immediately forward to the waiting EventSource listener in the browser.

This method is much more scalable than having your ruby webserver handle these "long-polling" SSE connections.

Comment: How can you make this highly available? like deploying 2 nginx instances and when you post a message to one of them, it is published to clients that are subscribed to both of them?

Answer (score 5):

Hi elevating this comment from [Did](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003254/did) to an answer: this is the only thing I needed to add  when streaming from Django using HttpStreamingResponse through Nginx. All the other switches above didn't help, but this header did.

Having the server respond with a "X-Accel-Buffering: no" header helps a lot! (see: wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Buffering) –
Did Jul 1, 2013 at 16:24