# NodeJS: Sending image files using SSE

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

I have a png file on the server side which is updated every second by a python script. I want to stream it to the client side using SSE so that it updates as the file updates.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/countdown', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'iimage/png;base64',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  })
  
  update(res);
})

function update(res) {
    const file = base64_encode("./public/pics/out.png");
    res.write(file);

    while (true) {
       
        wait(200);
        update(res);
    }
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('SSE app listening on port 3000!'))

function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
   }
 }

 function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  if (!!window.EventSource) {
    var source = new EventSource('/countdown')

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        var image = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
        image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + image;
    }, false)

  } else {
    console.log("Your browser doesn't support SSE")
  }
  </script>
<img id="img" src=""/>
</html>
```

I researched how to do it and tried this but it didn't work without any error. What can I modify to make it work?

Comment: 1. `img` doesn't have a closing tag. 2. What should changing `innerHTML` of `img` do?

Comment: @Konrad I've updated the code. When I manually insert the image path into the src of img, it brings the image but apparently, the script part of the html doesn't work and it doesn't make it update for some reason.

Comment: Where exactly are you using SSE?  I can't find appropriate headers...

Comment: add the `package.json` file to your question. Try to create a minimal runnable demo project, such as on `codesandbox`.

Comment: @pierpy I am trying to implement over this example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249684/simple-way-to-implement-server-sent-events-in-node-js . Which uses HTML's script to update it apparently.

Comment: @Toprak your `EventSource` never fires, because you do not send appropriate header : `Content-Type: text/event-stream`. Also, you have to manually write data in response