# Istio ingress gateway configuration for EventSource

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, istio, server-sent-events, eventsource

I am using Spring SSEEventEmitter library to publish events from server-side to client. Clients will subscribe for the event in first call and listen to server sent events.

I have deployed the application on Kubernetes which is enabled with Istio. Rest API is exposed for subscribing for the server events. Istio Ingress Gatway is used to be able to access API outside the Mesh/Kubernetes.

There is a similar issue has [been raise][1] for configuration on Nginx Ingress which is solved by adding K8s annotations (nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/eventsource: "true") to Nginx Ingress object.

Is there similar configuration available for Istio Ingress Gateway as well?

Comment: What is the issue here in istio exactly? AFAIK there is no option to set this in istio ingress gateway.

Comment: @jakub : Thanks for the reply. The browser cannot subscribe to the events (that SSEEmitter pushes from the server). There is a service timeout during the subscription API call only.

I get similar issue mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560048/sse-broken-after-deploying-with-kubernetes-and-connecting-via-ingress/64785310#64785310). In this case, I am using Istio Ingress Gateway.

Comment: Did you resolve this? @BasavarajDhanashetti