# How to configure gunicorn and gevent for sleep function inside a generator for Flask Server-Sent Events?

Tags: python, gunicorn, nonblocking, server-sent-events, gevent

I'm using this generator function to implement server-sent events:

```
def event_stream():
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(3)
        yield 'data: some data\n\n'
```

...and returning it like this:

```
return Response(event_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

If I use `time.sleep(3)` instead of `gevent.sleep(3)`, it blocks everything else (as expected). So, when I use `gevent` and run the Flask app locally, it works fine.

However, when I run it on remote server, it doesn't send messages in 3-second intervals like it did when I ran the app locally, but instead seems to keep on piling up the messages so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the server, all the messages that kept on piling up are dumped at once at the client side.

So, after about 30 seconds of waiting without any messages, when I kill the remote server, the ten messages that should have been received in the 3-second intervals get dumped at once.

I'm assuming this has something to do with how I'm running `gunicorn`. Here's how I'm currently starting the server:

```
gunicorn -c config.py server:app -k gevent
```

The only thing configured inside config file is the `bind` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of trying out so many things, it turned out that nginx configuration had to be changed for Server-Sent Events.

Merely adding these three lines did the trick:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
```

Source: [First Google Hit for "nginx server sent events" (SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673298/11774808)