# SSE event data gets cut off when using Nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, reverse-proxy, server-sent-events, chunked-encoding

I am implementing a web interface using React and Flask. One component of this interface is a server sent event that is used to update data in the front end whenever it is updated in a database. This data is quite large and one event could contain over 16000 characters.

The React front end uses a reverse proxy to the flask back end in order to forward API requests to it. When accessing this back end directly, this works fine with the SSEs and the data is pushed as expected. However, when using Nginx to serve the reverse proxy, something weird happens. It seems like nginx buffers and chunks the event stream and does not send the results until it has filled around 16000 characters. If the data from the event is smaller than this, it means the front end will have to wait until more events are sent. If the data from the event is larger, it means the new-lines that tell the EventSource that a message has been received aren't part of the event. This results in the front end receiving event X when event X+1 is sent (that is, when the new-lines actually appear in the stream).

This is the response header when using nginx:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 13:10:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is the response header when running `flask run` and accessing the port directly (I'm going to use `gunicorn` later but I tested with `flask run` to make sure nginx was the problem and not gunicorn):

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-transform
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: close
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.6
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 13:23:54 GMT
```

This is the nginx config in `sites-available`:

```
upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:6666;
}

server {
        listen 7076;
        root <path/to/react/build/>;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_cache off;
                chunked_transfer_encoding off;
        }
}
```

This config is based on the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx).

As you can see, both `proxy_buffering` and `chunked_transfer_encoding` is off, so I don't understand why this is happening. I have also tried changing the buffer sizes but without any luck.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? How do I fix it such that using nginx results in the same behaviour as when I don't use it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above mentioned configuration actually did work. However, the server I was using contained another nginx configuration that was overriding my configuration. When the configuration parameters specific for SSEs were added to that configuration as well, things started working as expected. So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx?noredirect=1&lq=1) was correct all along.

Comment: what configuration, can you explain this ?

Comment: The one I mentioned in the original question, i.e. "This is the nginx config in sites-available:". It worked as intended, but another nginx configuration on the server running the program was overriding this.