# Trying to host a flask app with flask-sse, the example code is unable to connect to redis, however redis-cli monitor shows activity

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redis, web-hosting, publish-subscribe

Im trying to get the [flask-sse](https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) example code to work on my raspberry pi 3. The website loads, but I get the message in the index.html in line 15 `Failed to connect to event stream. Is Redis running?` Redis is running and after trying multiple times I checked on it with `redis-cli monitor` it shows activity.

redis-cli monitor (shortened):

```
1676659598.612265 [0 [::1]:58788] "SUBSCRIBE" "sse"
1676659616.141010 [0 [::1]:39662] "SUBSCRIBE" "sse"
1676659624.109693 [0 [::1]:54564] "SUBSCRIBE" "sse"
1676659627.603954 [0 [::1]:54578] "PUBLISH" "sse" "{\"data\": {\"message\": \"Hello!\"}, \"type\": \"greeting\"}"
1676659627.614501 [0 [::1]:58788] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "sse"
1676659627.621229 [0 [::1]:39662] "UNSUBSCRIBE" "sse"
1676659651.509510 [0 [::1]:53316] "SUBSCRIBE" "sse"
```

(i was reloading the pages so that's why it happend multiple times, but none of them showed results)

to start the server:

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx
$ redis-server --daemonize yes
$ gunicorn sse:app --worker-class gevent --workers=3 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --daemon
```

the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sse import sse

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["REDIS_URL"] = "redis://localhost"
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/stream')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/hello')
def publish_hello():
    sse.publish({"message": "Hello!"}, type='greeting')
    return "Message sent!"
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flask-SSE Quickstart</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Flask-SSE Quickstart</h1>
  <script>
    var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('sse.stream') }}");
    source.addEventListener('greeting', function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        alert("The server says " + data.message);
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        alert("Failed to connect to event stream. Is Redis running?");
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out it didn't work due to the nginx config, found an answer here: [EventSource / Server-Sent Events through Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx)