# SSE connection in pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx-config, server-sent-events, puma

I was trying to implement SSE with Rails using a Puma server.

I followed this [post](https://medium.com/@thilonel/fixing-request-queuing-with-server-sent-events-using-ruby-on-rails-86a9177cb2f), which guides SSE implementation with partial hijacking. For testing purposes what I did differently is instead of a `while loop` I loop for definite times for writing to the stream. Locally the implementation works great. Then I deployed it to my staging server which sits behind a Nginx.

In the staging server, the implementation's behavior is a bit different. My observations were as follows in the staging server:

If I was doing sth like:

```
sse = SSE.new(...)
5.  Times do
  sse.write(...)
  sleep 2
end
```

then the request remained in a `pending` state for about 10 seconds. and only then do I get the results altogether which in my opinion is not the correct behavior. The same code is in my local environment; I received a stream every 2 seconds for 5 times.

This got me confused as to why I got the stream altogether and not in a sequential manner in the staging. If anyone with experience could shed some light on this, please??!

I followed the accepted answer for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx) for my nginx configuration.

Comment: Found the issue. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx

It is important to note that if you are using a proxy server then it makes a difference in how the SSE behaves. In case a proxy server sits before your backend server then don't forget to append `x-accel-buffering` in the response headers and set its value as `no`. So something like: `response.headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'`

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx for proxy server setup.

Hope it helps!