# true proper way of configuring nginx as a reverse proxy for an SSE endpoint

Tags: http, nginx, server-sent-events

I've seen everywhere what is summarized in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673298/2188076, that you have to add

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection '';
```

to your configuration for the SSE location.

I've done so and I have the following:

```
location /sse {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/sse;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
  }
```

and what I've noticed that makes me feel odd about this is that if I curl -v http://localhost:3000/sse in the response headers I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: identity
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2023 21:28:54 GMT
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
:ok
```

whereas if I curl to the nginx reverse proxy I get

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2023 21:29:35 GMT
< Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 
:ok
```

and that Connection: close makes me uneasy. I want to know why nginx is responding with Connection: close instead of keep-alive and how would I make it respond with keep-alive