How to flush Server-Sent Events (SSE) message without disconnecting in nodejs express
We would like to notify the frontend when new events arrive in the system, if they are part of the group that the event belongs to. We decided to use SSE to accomplish this over WebSockets since we only need unidirectional communication.
The issue we ran into was that the messages sent from the server would only show up on the frontend once the server was shut down. After some googling it turns out that we must close the connection in order to "flush" the message to the frontend.
This presents another issue, while the frontend is attempting to re-establish the SSE connection the client could miss out on notifications. Also, closing the connection and forcing the client to re-establish the connection doesn't seem like a good workflow, defeats the purpose of a long living connection through which the server can send messages to the frontend.
Shopify seems to be able to do it on their biggest data streaming event, so I think we should be able to as well.
Any direction in this matter would be appreciated.
Here is the pertinent code.
backend endpoint:
async function sse(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const userId = req.userId;
  if (!userId) {
    logger.error("[SSE] No user id in request. Forbidden.");
    res.status(403).send("Forbidden");
    return;
  }

  if (!connectedClients.has(userId)) {
    logger.info(`[SSE] Getting user ${userId} for SSE connection.`);
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: userId },
      include: { configuration: true, group: true },
    });

    if (!user) {
      logger.error(`[SSE] User ${userId} not found. Forbidden.`);
      res.status(403).send("Forbidden");
      return;
    }
    connectedClients.add(userId);
    for (const group of user.group) {
      if (!connectedClientGroups.has(group.id)) {
        connectedClientGroups.set(group.id, []);
      }
      connectedClientGroups.get(group.id).push({ userId, res });
    }
    logger.info(`[SSE] User ${userId} connected.`);
  }

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": FRONTEND_URL,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
  });

  // getRmqClient is a singleton, so we don't need to worry about multiple connections
  const rmqClient = await RmqClient.getRmqClient({
    connectionUrl: RMQ_URL,
    directExchangeName: RMQ_EXCHANGE,
    fanoutExchangeName: BROADCAST_EXCHANGE,
    eventQueue: EVENT_QUEUE,
    jobQueue: RMQ_JOB_QUEUE,
    emailJobQueue: RMQ_EMAIL_JOB_QUEUE,
  });

  await rmqClient.registerSSEConsumer(async (chan, msg) => {
    if (msg) {
      logger.info("[SSE] Received message from RMQ");
      const sseAlert: Alert = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
      const sseGroup = sseAlert.group_id;
      if (connectedClientGroups.has(sseGroup)) {
        // Confirm that the user still has access to the group
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { id: userId },
          include: { group: true },
        });
        if (!user || !user.group.find((group) => group.id === sseGroup)) {
          const oldList = connectedClientGroups.get(sseGroup);
          connectedClientGroups.set(
            sseGroup,
            oldList.filter((client: { userId: number; res: Response }) => client.userId !== userId)
          );
          chan.ack(msg);
          // We don't disconnect the user since they may have access to other groups
          return;
        }
        const alertCategory = await prisma.category.findUnique({
          where: {
            id: sseAlert.primary_category_id,
          },
        });
        for (const client of connectedClientGroups.get(sseGroup)) {
          logger.info(`[SSE] Sending new alert notification to user ${client.userId}`);
          client.res.write(
            `data: ${JSON.stringify({
              ...sseAlert,
              category: alertCategory,
              sseType: "newAlertNotification",
            })}\n\n`
          );
          // We have to close the connection after sending the message to ensure the client receives it since there
          // is no content length header in SSE, which means old proxies in between may hold the message until the
          // stream closes. source: https://dev.to/miketalbot/server-sent-events-are-still-not-production-ready-after-a-decade-a-lesson-for-me-a-warning-for-you-2gie
          client.res.end();
        }
      }
      chan.ack(msg);
    }
  });

  const heartbeatInterval = setInterval(() => {
    res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ sseType: "heartbeat" })}\n\n`);
    res.end();
  }, 30000);

  res.on("close", () => {
    clearInterval(heartbeatInterval);
    connectedClients.delete(userId);
    for (const group of connectedClientGroups.keys()) {
      const oldList = connectedClientGroups.get(group);
      connectedClientGroups.set(
        group,
        oldList.filter((client: { userId: number; res: Response }) => client.userId !== userId)
      );
    }
    logger.info(`[SSE] User ${userId} disconnected.`);
  });
}

frontend:
  const [sseConnected, setSseConnected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP__API_URL || "http://localhost:3001";
    let eventSource: ReconnectingEventSource;

    const connectSSE = () => {
      if (!sseConnected) {
        eventSource = new ReconnectingEventSource(`${baseUrl}/sse`, {
          withCredentials: true,
        });

        eventSource.onopen = () => {
          setSseConnected(true);
        };

        eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
          const newAlert = JSON.parse(event.data);
          console.log("SES New alert notification: ", newAlert);
        };

        eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
          setSseConnected(false);

          if (
            (error.target as EventSource)?.readyState !== EventSource.CLOSED &&
            (error.target as EventSource)?.readyState !== EventSource.CONNECTING
          ) {
            console.error("SSE connection error: ", error);
          }
        };
      }
    };


I've tried upgrading nginx proxy from the default 1.0 to 1.1.
I also tried to find a way to "flush" the stream like in this shopify code example but the only flushing available in nodejs for express seems to be res.end() which closes the connection.
I've tried adding the header "X-Accel-Buffering", "no".
I really want SSE to work since it fits the solution space so well, but will resort to using WebSockets if this doesn't work out.


Found the answer in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414096/26438225. However, now the connection gets closed after sending the message (I have removed the res.end() calls). Likely a nginx issue.
